# What happens in the following assembly commands?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

Just a precaution. I'm a complete noob on assembly. My only question is that only the following commands in DOS:

```
MOV  AH, 09
INT  21

MOV  AX, 4C01
INT  21
```

Does the second interrupt still have the parameter `09` meaning display screen or does the `AX` change that in some way?

Comment: Should that be `MOV AX, 4c01`?

Comment: `INT` are interrupt calls.

Comment: Yes it should be thanks

Comment: Int 21 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293699/what-does-int-21h-mean-in-assembly

Comment: loxxy I'm aware that int21 is a call the DOS's API I'm just completely oblivious to how the values in ah change and how the int call's paramter changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search for [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm), it's the definitive guide to these old DOS/Windows interrupts.

Calling [INT 21h with AH = 09H](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) outputs a `$`-terminated string located at `DS:DX` to the console.

Calling [INT 21H with AH = 4cH](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm) exits your program with the return code in `AL` (01H in this case).

The second call will *not* have `AH` set to `09H` simply because `AH` is simply the upper 8 bits of `AX`. The second `MOV` sets `AH` to `4cH` as part of setting `AX`:

[image]

---

In more detail (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086)):

[image]

---

This register-made-from-other-registers has a long history at Intel with:

- `ax` being made up of `ah` and `al`;
- `eax` being made up from 16 bits plus the other 16 from `ax`;
- `rax` being made up of 32 bits plus the other 32 from `eax`.

along with similar approaches for the other general purpose registers *and* special registers like index or base registers, and the stack pointer.

Interestingly enough, they *didn't* duplicate the ability to access the high halves of the expanded registers, such as with `eax` being made up of `eah` and `eal` (both mythical, but the latter being an alias for `ax`).

That would have given us a large cache of extra small registers in higher modes, though I'm not sure what the cost would have been (no doubt Intel/AMD *do* know the cost and it was probably deemed too expensive).

Comment: Thanks for the link to Ralf's website amazing list, now I just have to get over the couple of hours misinterpreting Assembly.

Answer (score 3):

`AH` and `AL` are the high and low halves of `AX`, respectively.  So yes, setting `AX` changes `AH`.

`4C` is "exit program".